# How to hide form fileds based on radio group selection ? Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle-apex

[How the form looks !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZttBJ.png)

Hi, so I was wondering what I need to do to hide the fields `Rezervacija FK` or `Brodica FK` based on the selection of the radio group `Vrsta Racuna`.

So basically I want to hide `Rezervacije FK` if `'MARINA'` is selected in the radio group. And hide `Brodica FK` if `SPORT` is selceted.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?  My guess is in dynamic actions but I cant seem to figure it out. Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out!

All you need to do is to make a dynamic action on the radio group where the *When* tab is set to event:

Change Selection Type:
*Item(s)* Items(s) `Pn_radio_group_name` in the `Client-side Condition` set Type:

```
Item = Value`,
Item: Pn_radio_group_name
Value: <your desired value>
```

and if that's true you hide the field you want to hide and if false you show the field and that's it.

Hope this helped anyone, its a very simple thing most people will find out on their own xD